# How to access RadSideDrawer from page?

Tags: nativescript

In Nativescript 5.x (TypeScript) I have successfully used the following code to access a RadSideDrawer:

```
import * as app from "@nativescript/core/application";
import { EventData } from "@nativescript/core/data/observable";
import { RadSideDrawer } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer";    

export function drawerLoaded(args: EventData) {
    let sideDrawer = <RadSideDrawer>args.object;      <--- error  
}
```

Now,with Nativescript 6.4 (and after migrating my app with "tns migrate") I am getting a compiler error on "tns build android":

> TS2352: Conversion of type 'View' to type 'RadSideDrawer' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

I have no idea how to fix this. Could anybody tell me what i need to change? That would be super nice. Thank you!

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue on my end, it may be something to do with your TS version or configurations. An easy fix is to cast the object to unknown type as the error description suggests - `let sideDrawer = <RadSideDrawer>(<any>args.object);`

Comment: Thank you Manoj. Ah, this is how you cast to "unknown". Thank you!! The compiler error went away. But now I am getting another compiler error, but I will put this on a seapate SO question. Btw: I just checked. "npm -list g" claims I am using TypeScript 2.9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce the issue on my end, it may be something to do with your TS version or configurations.

An easy fix is to cast the object to unknown type as the error description suggests.

```
let sideDrawer = <RadSideDrawer>(<any>args.object);
```