# No BindingContext in RadSideDrawer anymore?

Tags: nativescript

In Nativescript 5.x (TypeScript) I have successfully used the following code to assign a viewmodel to a RadSideDrawer's binding context:

```
    import * as app from "@nativescript/core/application";
    import { EventData } from "@nativescript/core/data/observable";
    import { RadSideDrawer } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer";    

    export function drawerLoaded(args: EventData) {
        let sideDrawer = <RadSideDrawer>args.object;  <-- compiler error 1
        sideDrawer.bindingContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
```

I then updated to Nativescript 6.4, TypeScript 2.9.2, RadSideDrawer 8.0.0 and then migrated my app with "tns migrate".

After all these updates I got a compiler error 1:

> TS2352: Conversion of type 'View' to type 'RadSideDrawer' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

SO user Manoj helped me to [solve this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60366256/how-to-access-radsidedrawer-from-page/60371428#60371428) (thank you again!). My current code now looks like this:

```
export function drawerLoaded(args: EventData) {
    let sideDrawer : RadSideDrawer = <RadSideDrawer>(<any>args.object);
    sideDrawer.bindingContext = new MyViewModel(); <-- compiler error 2
}
```

Now I got compiler error 2.

> Property 'bindingContext' does not exist on type
>   'RadSideDrawer'.ts(2339)

All of a sudden the RadSideDrawer has no binding context anymore? Even the [official documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/radsidedrawer) does not mention a BindingContext property anymore. What happened here?

[image]

Comment: I think 2.9.2 is too old. I don't face any issues as such with my projects, With Playground also it looks good while accessing bindingContext too. I use TypeScript 3.4 or 3.5.

Comment: Hm, maybe I was wrong. I ran "npm list -g" and found typescript@2.9.2 as one of the top entries. But when I run "tsc -v" I get "Version 3.8.2.". I have no idea what version TNS is using now. Do you know how I can make sure that TNS is using the new version? And then go from here with my error findings ... btw. I added a screen shot with my current code above. Maybe you do see something totally odd?

Comment: package.json says: "devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.5.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
So, concerning TypeScript I should be good, right?

Comment: Do you see compilation errors? If not, it's just something with VSCode configurations.

Comment: Yes, I do get compiler errors on "tns build android": TS2339: Property 'bindingContext' does not exist on type 'RadSideDrawer'.